# Are multiple "params" parameters possible?

Tags: c#, parameters

Is it possible to have multiple `params` parameters in C#? Something like this:

```
void foobar(params int[] foo, params string[] bar)
```

But I'm not sure if that's possible. If it is, how would the compiler decide where to split the arguments?

Comment: Welcome to [so] Gary, 5 answers listed in almost as many seconds. Why dont you pass in a param of classes? or a `<IEnum<IEnum>>`

Comment: What do you mean by passing in a param of classes?

Comment: I have been hit by lack of this feature :(

Comment: This is not allowed (params must be last argument). The compiler would decide to 3x int, because the default type of a number (without .) is int32. You'd neet do case Mult((long)1,(long)2) to get it to long.

Answer (score 48):

You can only have one params argument.  You can have two array arguments and the caller can use array initializers to call your method, but there can only be one params argument.

```
void foobar(int[] foo, string[] bar)

...

foobar(new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new[] { "a", "b", "c" });
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly the answer I was looking for :)

Comment: Upvoting for your 10th vote (giving you a badge) just because the OP didn't accept your answer. :)

Answer (score 39):

No this is not possible. Take this:

```
void Mult(params int[] arg1, params long[] arg2)
```

how is the compiler supposed to interpret this:

```
Mult(1, 2, 3);
```

It could be read as any of these:

```
Mult(new int[] {         }, new long[] { 1, 2, 3 });
Mult(new int[] { 1       }, new long[] {    2, 3 });
Mult(new int[] { 1, 2    }, new long[] {       3 });
Mult(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new long[] {         });
```

You can take two arrays as params like this however:

```
void Mult(int[] arg1, params long[] arg2)
```

Comment: because you state that as a reason for lack of this feature.

Comment: if type of the params groups are different then eachother, compiler can interpret.. for example lets say method(params int[] numbers, params string[] texts){}
 . method(34,76, "hi", "how are ya!");

Comment: Mult(1 , 2 , (long)3 , 5 , 6); after "3" it could be long parameters,

Comment: I wouldn't support something like that because implicit type casting is already a thing in c# and would royally mess things up. But supporting multiple params and just add an ambiguity warning just like with overloads and optional parameters wouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 26):

I know this is a super old post, but here:

In C# 7, you actually can. You can use `System.ValueTuple` to do this:

```
private void Foobar(params (int Foo, string Bar)[] foobars)
{
    foreach (var foobar in foobars)
        Console.WriteLine($"foo: {foobar.Foo}, bar: {foobar.Bar}");   
}

private void Main() => Foobar((3, "oo"), (6, "bar"), (7, "baz"));
```

Output:

```
Foo: 3, Bar: foo
Foo: 6, Bar: bar
Foo: 7, Bar: baz
```

<s>The only downside is you have to do this: `foobars[0].foo;` instead of `foos[0];`, but that's really a tiny tiny issue.</s>

### EDIT:

Using deconstructers, this becomes the previous "downside" goes away:

```
private void Foobar(params (int Foo, string Bar)[] foobars)
{
    // Deconstruct the tuple into variables
    foreach (var (foo, bar) in foobars)
        Console.WriteLine($"foo: {foo}, bar: {bar}");   
}
```

Comment: @anatol I guess that's worth noting but no one had mentioned attributes.

Answer (score 12):

From [MSDN - params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx)

> No additional parameters are permitted after the params keyword in a
>   method declaration, and **only one params keyword is permitted** in a
>   method declaration.

Answer (score 6):

No, only  a single param is allowed and even that has to be the last argument. Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx)

This will work

```
public void Correct(int i, params string[] parg) { ... }
```

But this won't work

```
public void Correct(params string[] parg, int i) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. It could be only one params keyword per method declarations - from MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
void useMultipleParams(int[] foo, string[] bar)
{
}


useMultipleParams(new int[]{1,2}, new string[] {"1","2"})
```

Comment: You did not use the params key word as it was asked in the question.